# What is the substitution of `::ink_storage::traits::push_spread_root::<Self>(self, &root_key);` in `ink 4.0.0-alpha.3`

Tags: ink

In 3.* version, I can use `::ink_storage::traits::push_spread_root::<Self>(self, &root_key);` very well.

What is the substitution in `ink 4.0.0-alpha.3`? I cannot find it anymore~

[image]

Comment: Go through [this link](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1400), now storage derives has moved to ink crate. you can use ::ink::storage::traits::push_spread_root::<Self>(self, &root_key);

Comment: Hey @Ganesh11, thanks a lot. But in fact, I have tried `::ink::storage::traits::push_spread_root::<Self>(self, &root_key);` before I asked the question here, and I met the problem below: `::ink::storage::traits::push_spread_root::<Self>(self, &root_key);
    |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in \`ink::storage::traits\``. And I cannot find `push_spread_root` and related `pull_spread_root` in the document.  So is there any other suggestions?

Comment: The functions `push_spread_root` and `push_spread_root` were removed in [this pull request](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1331). I don't know what is their replacement though.

Comment: [This instruction](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/a4594f0dfe91b69cd6ac603ad00aae17bfdd6ae4/crates/ink/codegen/src/generator/dispatch.rs#L820-L822) was previously (i.e. in 3.* version) using `push_spread_root`, but now there's a `set_contract_storage` call there. Maybe that's the function you're looking for?

Comment: And [here](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/a4594f0dfe91b69cd6ac603ad00aae17bfdd6ae4/crates/ink/codegen/src/generator/dispatch.rs#L835-L843) a call to `pull_spread_root` was replaced with `get_contract_storage`.

Comment: if you use `ink 4.0.0-alpha.3` version, then you can't find `push_spread_root and pull_spread_root` [look hear](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink/storage/traits/index.html), you can find those in `ink 3.00` version [look hear](https://docs.rs/ink_storage/3.0.0-rc3/ink_storage/traits/index.html) in function section. `pull_spread_root and _push_spread root` they take of type `T` which is `SpreadLayout` and this was omitted on latest version, you can [see here](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1331) on `2 commit`.

Comment: Shawn, it looks like @xgreenx answered your question in https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1400 and https://github.com/dantenetwork/protocol-stack-for-ink/pull/10, can you re-post the solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Hi as described in https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#storage-rework and https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1400
these traits have been removed as part of storage rework.
Please refer to Green's [example](https://github.com/dantenetwork/protocol-stack-for-ink/pull/10/files) to adapt your code.